# SQL group by number and replace characters

Tags: sql

I have data stored in my database for mobile numbers.
I want to group by the column `number` in the database.

For example, some numbers may show `44123456789` and `0123456789` which is the same number. How can I group these together?

Comment: Hi charlie! Can you show us what you already tried? Or at what point you're actually stuck? Then it is easier for us to help you :-)

Comment: "`44123456789` and `0123456789` which is the same number" - Really? Why do I think that this is not the same number?

Comment: Are these all UK numbers?

Comment: Substring, charindex, replace, regular Expressions. there are many ways to solve this,  most of them in easy tutorials when you google for sql...

Comment: I presume he meant this is the same phone number, the first one having the international prefix (+44) and the second one the optional leading number (0)

Comment: Calm down people - these are just different representations of the same phone number. Less coffee - lol...

Comment: hello, yes thats correct, different representations. they may not always be UK numbers

Comment: But if these numbers are not all UK numbers, how do you differenciate a German number from, let's say, a FR number ? both having the same count of digits once you remove the international prefix ?
I think you have some design issue if you have both international numbers and locally-formatted ones in the same column.

Comment: What DB you are using. Provide whatever you have tried so far. May be a demo would be a good stuff (http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: just phpmyadmin - mysql

Comment: @AHocevar if it is an international number, it will be formatted with the countries prefix and not 44 which is the UK prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DIGITS(column_name) FROM table_name
```

You should use this format in DB then you assign it any variable, next you can matching their digits with the others.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it really suits you, but you could build this kind of subquery:

```
SELECT ta.`phone_nbr`,
COALESCE(list.`normalized_nbr`,ta.`phone_nbr`) AS nbr
FROM (
  SELECT 
    t.`phone_nbr`,
    SUBSTRING(t.`phone_nbr`,2) AS normalized_nbr
  FROM `your_table` t
    WHERE LEFT(t.`phone_nbr`,1) = '0'
  UNION
  SELECT
    t.`phone_nbr`,
    sub.`filter_nbr` AS normalized_nbr
   FROM `your_table` t,
   ( SELECT 
       SUBSTRING(t2.`phone_nbr`,2) AS filter_nbr
     FROM `your_table` t2
      WHERE LEFT(t2.`phone_nbr`,1) = '0') sub
  WHERE LEFT(t.`phone_nbr`,1) != '0' 
    AND t.`phone_nbr` LIKE CONCAT('%',sub.`filter_nbr`)
) list
LEFT OUTER JOIN `your_table` ta
ON ta.`phone_nbr` = list.`phone_nbr`
```

It will return you a list of phone numbers with their "normalized" number, i.e. with the 0 or international prefix removed if there is a duplicate match, and the raw number otherwise.

You can then use a `GROUP BY` clause on the `nbr` field, join on the `phone_nbr` for the rest of your query.

It has some limits, as it can unfortunately group similar stripped numbers. +49123456789, +44123456789 and 0123456789 will unfortunately have the same normalized number.